# Array of hashes is overriding data directly to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I want to make an array of hashes. But the problem is after first iteration when code goes to next line then it directly replaces the content of array.

```
@item_name =[]
item = {}
@invoiceinfo.each do |invoice|
  item[:name] =  Invoiceinfo.find(@invoiceinfo.id).item.name
  item[:desc] =  Invoiceinfo.find(@invoiceinfo.id).desc
  item[:unit_price] =  Invoiceinfo.find(@invoiceinfo.id).unit_price
  byebug
  @item_name.push (item)
end
```

This is what i am getting
after first iteration suppose i have this data

```
@item_name = [{:name=>"usman", :desc=>"sample ", :unit_price=>100}]
```

As soon as next line is executed it directly changes @item_name(name variable)
After executing `item[:name] =  Invoiceinfo.find(@invoiceinfo.id).item.name`
the content of the **@item_name** is changed

> @item_name = [{:name=>"next_name", :desc=>"sample ", :unit_price=>100}]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thannks

Comment: There's a good answer, but to clarify what you're doing wrong you're just reassigning the value to the same keys over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
@item_name = []
@invoiceinfo.each do |invoice|
  invoice_info = Invoiceinfo.find(@invoiceinfo.id)

  item = {}
  item[:name] =  invoice_info.item.name
  item[:desc] =  invoice_info.desc
  item[:unit_price] = invoice_info.unit_price

  @item_name.push(item)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, i was not re-initializing the hash.

Comment: Exactly. And I made one SQL query for iteration, not three :) You're welcome

Comment: Good to see you provided the third line of code as a bonus.

Answer (score 4):

If you consider using ruby paradigms and best practices in ruby code, this mistake won’t happen in the future.

```
@item_name = @invoiceinfo.each_with_object([]) do |invoice, acc|
  invoice_info = Invoiceinfo.find(@invoiceinfo.id)

  acc.push(
    name: invoice_info.item.name,
    desc: invoice_info.desc
    unit_price: invoice_info.unit_price
  )
end
```